# C# Block class usage for example WebBrowser

Tags: c#

I am trying to stop other programmers from using a particular class (as a best practice, and consider alternatives).

More specific, I am trying to enforce the usage of WebClient or HttpRequest, instead of WebBrowser, because there have been numerous bugs related to WebBrowser usage that can leave open Threads or message loops and leave the application hanging, so it doesn't end/exit.

WebBrowser is more heavy weight,

I know it is possible to do it by locking like

```
lock (typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser))
{
}
```

but this has many drawbacks.

Is it possible to block usage of a certain class like WebBrowser in a C# project or file or solution?

A warning using a pragma would be even better

```
#warning Please avoid using WebBrowser, consider WebClient
```

Solutions for blocking a namespace is an option but only as a last resort

Comment: `I know it is possible to it by locking like ...` - I don't think [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) means what you think it means.

Comment: _"I know it is possible to it by locking like"_ - no, that does not do what you expect it to.

Comment: Marshall777 might be a genius, I'm investigating if this requires manually doing "Run code Analysis ..."

Comment: It does seem to require a manual run for the coding rules, so it doesn't trigger on build, but besides that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mateusz According to the link you provided "lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible." but it is possible to lock the type for the duration of the program, this would make code using WebBrowser fail, because the code would wait forever (deadlock), so it would send a signal to the programmer. I don't see your point in the code provided.

Comment: This sounds like something that would be a good match for PostSharp: http://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: @AlexandruLache: locking on a type variable (as you have in your code) doesn't stop anyone creating a new instance.  This code executes without stopping: `lock (typeof(System.Object)) { var o = new System.Object(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating [your own coding rule set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380660.aspx) which would warn when the WebBrowser class is used.

Answer (score 0):

Just use type check in method you are passing reference:

```
 if(someobject is (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser))
 { 
   throw new ArgumentException("Don't use web browser here naughty programmer");
 }
```

For lock statement I suggest reading (please don't use it that way you think of):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx